# how to make a condition for balance to print it

Tags: java

This code is to print these objects to file named **customer.txt**. It is working correctly but I am trying to put condition like if **balance>3000** print that object.
How can I declare balance? Should I read the bytes for balance and print it ?

```
 File a = new File("customer.txt");

 FileWriter v = new FileWriter(a);
 BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(v);
 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(b);


 human Iman = new human("Iman", 5000);
 human Nour = new human("Nour", 3500);
 human Redah = new human("Redah", 0);
 human iman = new human("iman", 200);
 human MohamedREDA = new human("MohamedREDA", 3000);
 human Mohamed_Redah = new human("Mohamed Redah", 2000);

 human[] h = new human[6];

 h[0] = Iman;
 h[1] = Nour;``
 h[2] = Redah;
 h[3] = iman;
 h[4] = MohamedREDA;
 h[5] = Mohamed_Redah;

 p.println(Iman);
 p.println(Nour);
 p.println(Redah);
 p.println(iman);
 p.println(MohamedREDA);
 p.println(Mohamed_Redah);

 p.flush();
 }

 }
 class human {
     public String name;
     public double balance;

     public human(String n, double b) {
         this.balance = b;
         this.name = n;

     }@
     Override
     public String toString() {
         return name + " " + balance;
     }
```

Comment: What about adding in toString method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your logic as below:

Loop through over the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < h.length; i++){    
    if(h[i].balance>3000){
        p.println(h[i]);   
    }
}
```

Comment: no no no no, `toString` is not intended to be implemented for this purpose. Your `toString` method should always return a textual representation of your object and never contain business logic like this.

Comment: yeah thanx all i put my condition in customer class